# How do I tweak Autohotkey scripts originally written for 1920p so they will scale properly on a 4k monitor?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to help a friend of mine with an Autohotkey issue.

He's done lots of scripting with AHK, but now he's got a new 4k monitor and many of his old scripts look broken -- he'd scripted everything for his old 1920p monitor.

Does anybody know if there's some simple way to adapt his scripts to his new screen resolution?

Or, is it absolutely necessary to go into the scripts and manually edit every single command that is resolution-dependent? I hope not!

My friend suspects it should be possible to code in some algorithm to resize all resolution-dependent commands automatically. Does that idea seem workable?

Thank you so much -- really hoping you can help us figure this out!

Comment: Whats the code look like? Do you have an example script you can link to?

Answer (score 0):

Your friend will be forced to go through manually an replace these. If it dependent on pixel perfect location then they will have to locate each elements location again. Setting variables to constants values for locations is a good way to make this easier to fix in the future.